# Python mock - return internal variable

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests

I'm trying to write a test for a script (my_script) in python. Partway through this script, a pandas dataframe is saved to AWS as a csv. I don't want to save a file to AWS every time I run this test, but I do want to be able to check the contents of this dataframe later on in the test. Is it possible to overwrite the 'save_to_csv' function inside my_script so that this dataframe persists? I have tried writing a simple class to store the dataframe as an attribute:

```
class FakeStorage(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dataframe = None
    def save_to_csv(self, df, file_path):
        self.dataframe = df
        print('df fake saved')


FAKE_STORAGE = FakeStorage()
import my_script
my_script.save_to_csv = FAKE_STORAGE.save_to_csv
```

and I have also tried persisting the dataframe as a global variable:

```
def fake_save_to_csv(df, file_path):
    global DATAFRAME
    DATAFRAME = df
    print('df fake saved')

import my_script
my_script.save_to_csv = fake_save_to_csv
```

Oddly, in both cases I see the print statement, so the function seems to have been successfully overwritten. However, after my_script has run in the test, in the first case I try to access FAKE_STORAGE.dataframe and it is None, in the second case trying to access DATAFRAME throws a NameError.

Does anyone have any other ideas to try?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work. Setting up a global variable the data frame can be stored in. Using side effects to save off the dataframe when the function is called.

```
import unittest
df = None. # global variable

class GlobalTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.mock.patch('script.save_to_csv')
    def test_aws_pull(self, mock_save_to_csv):
        mock_save_to_csv.side_effect = lambda x: df=x  # able to set global variable
        call_script()
        assert mock_save_to_csv.called  # test to see if used. you want to replace with what youd like tested

    def test_df(self):
        expected_df = 'what you expect the df to be'
        assert expected_df == df  # using thr gloval variable in the next test
```

Other possible solutions are test the dataframe in the same test function, save the dataframe as a class variable instead of a global variable, include the dataframe saving as a setUp function in a separate class, or using pytest create a dataframe fixture.